# RPC call, connection on demand or constant connection? what's the common pattern?

Tags: xml-rpc, rpc

I was thinking this question for a while, and ever tried to google but no answer got. Maybe my keyword was not accurate.

Is the connection in RPC library like XML-RPC on demand or constant? if it's constant, how it maintains huge numbers of connections? for example, if I have 100,000 agents to control. If it's on demand, how it overcomes the cost of establishing connection in frequent call? for instance, 1000 calls per second.

My best guess is there is a connection pool caching recent connections with a timeout. But not sure what's the common implementation.

Comment: let's say apache ws-xmlprc. But I think there should be a ordinary pattern that most xmlrpc libraries adopt.

Comment: It looks like not many people thinking about this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I looked into Apache XMLRPC library, it's based on httpcall, so it's connection on demand

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I'm thinking about using https://grpc.io/ but also not sure if it supports constant connections. But it looks very promising.